# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 15: invalid start byte

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
db = input("Enter the dataset name:")
table = db+".csv"
df = pd.read_csv(table)
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
with open(table,'rb') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)
    for row in data:
        rows = row
        break
print(rows)
```

**I am trying to read all the columns from the csv file.**

> ERROR: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 15: invalid start byte

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check encoding of your `csv` file.

For that you can use `print(f)`,

```
with open('file_name.csv') as f:
    print(f)
```

The output will be:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='file_name.csv' mode='r' encoding='utf8'>
```

Open `csv` with the encoding as mentioned in the above output,

```
with open(fname, "rt", encoding="utf8") as f:
```

As mentioned in comments,
your encoding is `cp1252`

so,

```
with open(fname, "rt", encoding="cp1252") as f:
    ...
```

and for `.read_csv`,

```
df = pd.read_csv(table, encoding='cp1252')
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for responding. It is showing encoding as **"cp1252"**. Then I placed encoding = 'cp1252' while opening csv, but it didn't work.

Comment: @harshavardhan Open like this `with open(fname, "rt", encoding="cp1252") as f:` If it solved your issue, don't forget to accept.

Comment: It is throwing error at line 5 of the code. `df = pd.read_csv(table)`       
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack.py", line 5, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(table)

Comment: @harshavardhan use `df = pd.read_csv(table, encoding='cp1252')`

Comment: Thank you! It's Working.