# "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 3965: invalid start byte" when using Pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an executable from two python scripts. One script defines the GUI for the other backend script. The backend is reading in excel files, creating DataFrames with them for manipulation, then outputting a new excel file. This is the code that reads in the excel file, where "user_path, userAN, userRev1, userRev2" are grabbed as user input from the GUI:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
from tkinter import messagebox
import os

def generate_BOM(user_path, userAN, userRev1, userRev2):
    ## Append filepath with '/' if it does not include directory separator
    if not (user_path.endswith('/') or user_path.endswith('\\')):
        user_path = user_path + '/'
    ## Set filepath to current directory if user inputted path does not exist
    if not os.path.exists(user_path):
        user_path = '.'
    
    fileFormat1 = userAN + '_' + userRev1 + '.xls'
    fileFormat2 = userAN + '_' + userRev2 + '.xls'
    
    for file in os.listdir(path=user_path):
        if file.endswith(fileFormat1):
            df1 = pd.read_excel(user_path+file, index_col=None) 
        
        if file.endswith(fileFormat2):
            df2 = pd.read_excel(user_path+file, index_col=None)
```

When running the two scripts through Spyder, everything works perfectly. To create the exe, I am using Pyinstaller with the following command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile Delta_BOM_Creator.py
```

This results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\davhar\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\davhar\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\davhar\Anaconda3\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\davhar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\davhar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\davhar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 737, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\davhar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 684, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\davhar\.spyder-py3\DELTA_BOM_Creator\Delta_BOM_Creator.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['Delta_BOM_Creator.py'],
  File "c:\users\davhar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 242, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\davhar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\davhar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 414, in assemble
    priority_scripts.append(self.graph.run_script(script))
  File "c:\users\davhar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 303, in run_script
    self._top_script_node = super(PyiModuleGraph, self).run_script(
  File "c:\users\davhar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1411, in run_script
    contents = fp.read() + '\n'
  File "c:\users\davhar\anaconda3\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 3965: invalid start byte
```

I've tried everything I could find that somewhat related to this issue. To list just a few:

[UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 15: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56881974/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x96-in-position-15-invalid)

https://www.dlology.com/blog/solution-pyinstaller-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte/

[Pandas read _excel: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa8 in position 14: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647122/pandas-read-excel-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa8-in-position-14-invalid/48647582)

I've never used Pyinstaller, or created an executable from python at all, so apologies for being a big time noob.

**SOLUTION:** I found a solution. I went into the codecs.py file mentioned in the error and added 'ignore' to line 322

```
(result, consumed) = self.buffer_decode(data, 'ignore', final)
```